Closed form of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^3}$
We know that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^1} = e$.
By considering the function $f(x,y) := \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(xy)^n}{(n!)^2}$ and taking the Laplace transform in $y$ of $f = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f$ , I have shown that
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^2} = \frac{1}{\pi}\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi} e^{2\cos(\theta)} d\theta
\end{equation}
Can we find a closed form, or integral representation of the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^3}$? Or perhaps the more general $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n!)^p}$?
I tried to solve the problem with $p=3$ by using the same method as above by considering the function $f(x,y,z) := \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(xyz)^n}{(n!)^3}$. I then tried to take a Laplace transform of the equation $f = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} f$ in $z$, and then in $y$. However, I could not make any progress with this method.

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(n!)^3}=, _0F_2(;1,1;1)$ and $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(n!)^4}=, _0F_3(;1,1,1;1)$  where $_0F_3$ is generalized hypergeometric function.

@MariuszIwaniuk I am not familiar with this notation. Could you provide a link?

See: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html

Numerical value is $$2.1297025489833064181345236105954134682$$

@Peter Found it on OEIS with your numerical evaluation: https://oeis.org/A271574

Mathematica code for general $p$: f[p_] := HypergeometricPFQ[{}, Table[1, {p - 1}], 1]; Table[f[p], {p, 1, 4}] gives: $\left{e,I_0(2),, _0F_2(;1,1;1),, _0F_3(;1,1,1;1)\right}$

It is unfortunate these integral representations do not directly apply. Possibly converting $_0F_3$ into $_p F_q$ functions with larger $p,q$ would work.

You can get a complex integral representation using the inverse Laplace transform and taking the Laplace transform of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!^k}$, which reduces $k$ by $1$.

@ТymaGaidash Are you able to demonstrate this in an answer?

I couldn't reproduce your result with the Laplace transform, can you post the details please?

$\def\F{\text F}$The Laplace transform can be applied in another way:
$$\text L_x(_0\F_{p-1}(;1,\dots,1,x))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\frac{x^n}{n!^p}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{s^{-p-1}}{n!^{p-1}}=\frac1s\,_0\F_{p-2}\left(;1,\dots,1;\frac1s\right)$$
If we apply the inverse Laplace transform, we can express this $_0\F_j$ as an integral of $_0\F_{j-1}$:
$$\boxed{\begin{aligned}_0\F_{p-1}(;1,\dots,1;x)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{e^{sx}}s\,_0\F_{p-2}\left(;1,\dots,1;\frac1s\right)ds,c>0\end{aligned}}$$
It seems that $c>0$ since there is singularity at $s=0$. Repeatedly applying the formula will give multidimensional inverse Laplace transform representations analogous to the real multiple integrals for $_p\F_q$:
$$\boxed{\begin{aligned}_0\F_{p-1}(;1,\dots,1;x)= \frac1{(2\pi i)^j}\int_{c_1-i\infty}^{c_1+i\infty}\!\!\!\dots \int_{c_j-i\infty}^{c_j+i\infty}\frac{e^{s_1 x+\frac{s_2}{s_1}+\dots+\frac{s_j}{s_{j-1}}}}{s_1\dots s_j}\,_0\F_{p-1-j}\left(;1,\dots,1;\frac1{s_j}\right)ds_j\dots ds_1\\=\frac1{(2\pi i)^{p-1}}\int_{c_1-i\infty}^{c_1+i\infty}\!\!\!\dots \int_{c_{p-1}-i\infty}^{c_{p-1}+i\infty}\frac{e^{s_1 x+\frac{s_2}{s_1}+\dots+\frac{s_{p-1}}{s_{p-2}}+\frac1{s_{p-1}}}}{s_1\dots s_{p-1}}ds_{p-1}\dots ds_1\end{aligned}}$$
Additionally,  If $p=2$, we get a known integral representation for $_0\F_1(;1;x)$ and if $p=3,x=1$, we get:
$$_0\F_2(;1,1;1)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{e^s}s\,_0\F_1\left(;1;\frac1s\right)ds= -\frac1{4\pi^2}\int_{c_1-i\infty}^{c_1+i\infty}\int _{c_2-i\infty}^{c_2+i\infty}\frac{e^{\frac ws+\frac1w+s}}{ws}dwds$$
as shown here:



Perhaps it is possible to find a real integral, but that requires finding the real part of $_0\text F_1(1,a+b i)$. Since $_0\text F_1$ is a Bessel function, we can try using Kelvin functions, but they are limited.
